# How can I move a boot partition onto a Flash drive?

Tags: 11.04, server, boot, partitioning, usb-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 Server onto an Acer Aspire Easystore H340-M.

It was a Windows Home Server. The hardware has an integral Flash Drive / USB (SCSI11) of 256 Mb.

Could I use this as the boot partition? If so any pointers on what I should do?

Comment: By RAM Drive I assume you mean Flash drive?

Comment: Have you been able to identify which device the drive is in /dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is a flash drive and not ram ( therefore, it remembers its contents when you shut down ), 250 mb is insufficient to install the system to, so no.

Comment: That would only apply for the root partition, which is not the same as boot. Boot could be tiny, as it would only have grub config, a kernel and an initrd image. It should easily fit into 256Mb. You would then need a larger drive though. Adding as a comment not answer, because I'd need to play with the hardware to know what'd work.

Comment: @Danny Staple, technically yes, but I assumed the OP actually meant root partition, since placing only the boot partition on the flash drive would do no good.

Comment: True - however, I am relatively sure there are tiny live distro's that fit - I think there are a couple that come in under 64Mb. For example - http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/.